# How can I use s3cmd to move only the files that changed to Amazon S3 ?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, backup

```
s3cmd put --recursive /mydir s3://mybucker/
```

This is the way I currently upload my directory to S3.
I run this every night to backup my stuff.

However, it's getting too big. I only want to upload files that was modified instead of every file. How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try out the s3cmd sync option something like the following

```
s3cmd sync  /mydir  s3://mybucker/
```

Comment: You can refer to the following site which explains it http://s3tools.org/s3cmd-sync 
Sync does a version check on file before upload to s3 and upload file that have changed locally